# pandas merged multiple dataframes of different size and columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have many dataframes from 0 to N that need to merge. They all has one common column called 'NAME'. I tried different ways on merge and concat but dataframes doesn't return the format I need

These are some samples of my data

```
d1 = {'col1': [1,1], 'col2': [1,1], 'NAME': ["A","A"]}
d2 = {'col3': [1,1], 'col4': [1,1], 'NAME': ["A","A"]}
d3 = {'col1': [2,2], 'col2': [2,2], 'NAME': ["B","B"]}
d4 = {'col3': [2,2], 'col4': [2,2], 'NAME': ["B","B"]}
d5 = {'col5': []}
d6 = {'col5': []}

df_list = [d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6]

test_df = []
for item in df_list:
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame(data=item)
    test_df.append(temp_df)

merged = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on="NAME", how='outer'),test_df)
```

The above code also give me an error: KeyError: 'NAME'

I expect my merged result to be

```
   col1 col2 col3 col4 NAME
0     1    1    1    1    A
1     1    1    1    1    A
0     2    2    2    2    B
1     2    2    2    2    B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming unique NAME values per dataframe, I would use [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) here:

```
(pd
 .concat(test_df).rename_axis('index')
 .groupby(['NAME', 'index']).first()
 .reset_index('NAME')
)
```

output:

```
      NAME  col1  col2  col3  col4
index                             
0        A   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
1        A   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
0        B   2.0   2.0   2.0   2.0
1        B   2.0   2.0   2.0   2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
d1 = {'col1': [1,1], 'col2': [1,1], 'NAME': ["A","A"]}
d2 = {'col3': [1,1], 'col4': [1,1], 'NAME': ["A","A"]}
d3 = {'col1': [2,2], 'col2': [2,2], 'NAME': ["B","B"]}
d4 = {'col3': [2,2], 'col4': [2,2], 'NAME': ["B","B"]}
d5 = {'col5': []}
d6 = {'col5': []}

df_list = [d1, d2, d3, d4]

test_df = []
for item in df_list:
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame(data=item)
    test_df.append(temp_df)

merged = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on="NAME", how='outer'),test_df)
merged["col5"] = None
```

|  | col1_x | col2_x | NAME | col3_x | col4_x | col1_y | col2_y | col3_y | col4_y | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | A | 1 | 1 | nan | nan | nan | nan |  |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | A | 1 | 1 | nan | nan | nan | nan |  |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | A | 1 | 1 | nan | nan | nan | nan |  |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | A | 1 | 1 | nan | nan | nan | nan |  |
| 4 | nan | nan | B | nan | nan | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |  |
| 5 | nan | nan | B | nan | nan | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |  |
| 6 | nan | nan | B | nan | nan | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |  |
| 7 | nan | nan | B | nan | nan | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |  |

[pandas.DataFrame.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

If you just want to expand one column, then you can add a separate column without merge

`KeyError: 'NAME'`